# Bluetooth headphones sound odd when enabling them as input

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and have on-ears Bose headphones. If I connect the headphones via bluetooth to use them as output device (listen to music etc.) everything works fine. However as soon as I set them to be used as input device the sound becomes really rusty. This seems to be only happening on Ubuntu. Also once I have set them as output device the sound issue will not go away unless I reconnect them.